# React/Redux Form ReRender Method

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rendering, redux-form

I would like to insert advertisement block (such as Google Adsense) inside of items list. I am using the react-redux & react-connect. Even if I need to refresh the feed and rerender, I would like to run the render of ad-block div only one time. Is there any way we can do this?

```
render(){

    const { feed } = this.props;

    return(

        <div>

            <div class="ad-block"><!-- Need To Render one time --></div>

            <div class="items">

                {_.map(feed.data, item => {

                    return <div class="item">.......</div>

                })}

            </div>

            <div class="ad-block"><!-- Need To Render one time --></div>

    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about to split it in 3 components?

```
export const Something = () => ( 
<>
 <AdBlock>
 <Feed>
 <AdBLock>
<>
);
```

And connect Feed separately through Redux.